How to pass a json string from Jenkins Parameter to Shell ansible argument
I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs a shell script that includes a bit of ansible. The ansible portion of the script takes an argument from Jenkins job ANSIBLE_ARG. This parameter can take any number of arguments -v, -b, or in the case of this question -e.
However when I pass a json string to the -e flag ansible is unable to process command.
pipeline {
  
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'ANSIBLE_ARG', defaultValue='', description='argument to pass to ansible)
  }
  stages {
    stage('reproduce ansible error') {
      steps {
        sh '''
echo "${ANSIBLE_ARG}"
ansible -i localhost, -c local ${ANSIBLE_ARG} all -m debug -a "var=key"
        '''
    }
  }
}

I call it with ANSIBLE_ARG set to -e {"key":"some value with spaces"}
Ansible throws an error stating unrecognized arguments "with spaces".
The command being echoed shows that single quotes (') are being added at various points in the substitution ansible -i localhost, -c local -e '{"key":"some' value with 'spaces"}' all -m debug -a "var=key"
Is there a way to get Jenkins no inject the single quotes into the middle of my json?

There are several issues in the pipeline where one or more may be root cause, but the most important question is whether you can use the Pipeline Plugin for Ansible https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansible/. That would fix the interpretation issues immediately.

You would need to fix your extra argument to run this manually from the command line anyway => -e '{"key":"some value with spaces"}'. What happens if you type exactly this (i.e. with the outer single quotes) as ANSIBLE_ARG?

You are doing the right thing with echo - you quote your variable expansion. Do the same when you call ansible
ansible -i localhost, -c local "${ANSIBLE_ARG}" all -m debug -a "var=key"

A linter would have told you that. That's why nested syntax is a bad idea.

Thank you.   Quoting the shell variable helped but didn't solve the problem.  It gives me a new problem.. localhost | SUCCESS => { "key": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" }

This gives the same result from a real tty shell as well.
